# What is the DC behavior of the switched BJT emitter follower configuration

Tags: bjt, common-collector

There is a circuit shown below where we have a sub-circuit I marked in red.

I know that it is a source follower with the AC behavior shown below.

As you can see the circuit has DC voltage input only.
What is the DC behavior of the part I marked with the red arrow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are two conditions - when Q2 is turned on and when Q2 is turned off. Solve using the DC conditions - ie how much base current flows.

Comment: Hello KARTMAN in NPN Vb>Ve(base emitter foward biased junction) Vc>Vb (base collector reverse biased junction)
These are the condition for the diode to be in active region.

but it doesnt say the logic of the block.
I dont know what is Vb and what is Vout1

Comment: This tends to be poor design for FET shootthru making this an XY question, or bad assumption to analyze for half bridges

Comment: Lub, It's pretty clear, from the addition of the diode across the base emitter junction of Q3 that a pull up resistor is at the emitter (or some other reason to need to sink current when Q2 is saturated.) There is little chance that's there for some unknown inductor because the emitter sources current, it doesn't sink it and that diode won't continue to source current, if needed. It can only sink current when Q2 is saturated. (Of course, that assumes an intelligent designer. ;)

Comment: It’s an XY question based on his last comment to me.

Answer (score 1):

let’s consider linear vs non-linear differences.

We know from datasheet typical curves and min/typ/max specs how hFE varies with Ic, Temperature and Vce.

- since Zout is a direct function of hFE, and impedance applied to the base it is important to understand some variables and how impedance control rise fall time into some fixed charge , Q or estimated Ciss which is also Vgs voltage dependent.
- When Vce=Vce(sat) at Ic/Ib=10, and hFE typ is 100 we know that hFE has lost 90% of it’s value due to forward conduction of Vcb.  Similar 10% ratio exists for hFE types >500 tested at Ic/Ib=50.  But since hFE is too dynamic, we standardize Vce(sat) at fixed Ic/Ib ratios even though we know Ic is only controlled by Vbe.  But with Re/Rfb ratios known it is easier to compute Vce(sat) from current ratios than otherwise.
- the Zout formula is better defined by hFE than gm because gm not given in datasheets.

$$Zo_{emitter}=( Z_{Input}/h_{FE})// Re//Ro. $$

- for Q3, Zinput=R6//Rce(Q2), neglecting flyback D1.
  We assume R6>>Rce which is the saturation condition =Vce(sat)/Ic,
- therefore we know Zo rises when Q2 turns off leaving R6/hFE to define the Zo
- When Q2 turns on, it’s Rce drops to 1 Ohm for PN2222A and equivalents. Vb will be <100 mV, then Ve depends solely on the passive pull down load resistance.

This means using a emitter follower will have a faster risetime due to R6/hFE than fall time due to the load resistance unless it is less than R6/hFE.

Since Complementary drivers like this always needs a deadtime to prevent shootthru, the final switch turn off time must be faster than turn on time.  that means emitter followers make poor half bridge drivers so push-pull drivers are used instead with controlled slew impedances.

Comment: Hello Tony,there is no AC behavior in here only DC.

Hello KARTMAN in NPN Vb>Ve(base emitter foward biased junction) Vc>Vb (base collector reverse biased junction) These are the condition for the diode to be in active region. but it doesnt say the logic of the block. I dont know what is Vb and what is Vout1

Comment: Hey @rocko445 the DC condition has two states which I defined using \$h_{FE}\$ the dc gain and did not use \$H_{fe}\$ the ac current gain. Got it? Sorry Vb of Q3 and Vout1 =Ve(Q3) depends on load and Zo

Comment: It’s not a good solution . It ought to be complementary state equal impedances i.e. push-pull or CMOS for driving FETs but to drive a suitable coil at suitable f without saturation currents. Then OK to analyze further

Comment: Hello Tony,Yes there is active and there is saturation and there is cuttoff depending on the junctions ,you blended a lot of exelent  AC behavior .but my whole circuit has negative DC input.

looking at the whole circuit what do you think the DC behavior of the red circled block?
Thanks.

Comment: It cannot be examined in isolation without AC analysis of the load such as L or a motor. But essentially DC differential impedance of both Vout’s will always be limited by Rb/hFE being higher than diode, Rs and Rce/hFE defined by some current limit. this means Rb must dissipate a lot of heat when Q2 is ON for Rb to be as small as possible, so not so great

Comment: Edited comment that was backwards. E.g, Zo=Rfb/hFE for Vce> 1V or less than 1V hFE reduces towards 90% loss so power dissipation efficiency Vce*Ic is poor for a switch

Comment: Hello Tony ,So if i understnad you correcty this is some sort of switch.Is it switching on and off the vdd_400?
what is the role of R6 ? Rfb is R6 in your explanantion ?why do we need a diode?between emitter and base?Thanks.

Comment: My crystal ball says this was used for an inductive load and the diode is a flyback switch when Q shuts off. Again R6 =R8 dominate the current limit on output from Zo=R6/hFE + load impedance across differential voltage.  See that the lower circuit has an extra inverter.

Comment: So current limit is controlled by R6 and R8. insufficient current means both Q3 and Q5 get hot so these R values must also be low to work , but still not as good as bipolar or dual Nch half bridge using PWM on the lower channel to create a boost voltage for an upper Nch driver > vdd_400 to drive Vgs =>2.5 vgs(th)

Comment: Some people may attempt to use this cct  for Center-tapped (polar single supply) stepper motors for full steps or other circuits.  But not at 400V .  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Bipolar%20motor%20driver. Vdd implies FET  While Vcc implies collector loads

Comment: Hello Tony, its not 400 but 200,it was a mistake.could you please say what did you mean to say if it was 200

Comment: Ok no difference, but with known Z(f) of load and input spectrum , DC analysis is assumed to be best case. Ac Zo is higher. Unless there is shootthru across supply! Due to risetime being faster than fall time.

Comment: Basically emitter follower is a unity gain voltage follower in forward active with Zo=Rb/hFE where hFE is a function of Vce/Vce(sat) being current dependent due to Rce(sat) so the saturation voltage rises with current, which has nothing to do with ro

Comment: Hello Tony,Could you please recomment me a simple LTSPLICE simulation so i could see the R6 role and the diode role.
What components to use,what voltages to use,What input to use.
Just to see in your excelent explanation in simulation that i will try and build in LTSPICE

Comment: I hate LTspice go look for my Falstad simulations

Comment: Maybe you can learn how to draw schematics and choose plots here https://tinyurl.com/yk6lx9tn this is a  complementary Darlington where you can examine Pd for base, supply and load to see the changes with pot sliders and fixed hFE

Comment: Hello Tony,I have tried to simulate the circuit in LTSPICE(sorry its what i know)
i changed Vdd to 30V to fit the datasheet bellow.
From the datasheet shown bellow.
How to decide what R and diode to use so i will get 30V switching instead of Vin=Vout behavior that i got?
Thanks.

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/246437/RENESAS/2N3904.html
As you can see its giving me Vin=Vout instead of 30 Volt switching on and off.
Thanks.
https://ibb.co/VxkWB90
https://ibb.co/4NhS3VY

Comment: Search “high side switch” everywhere including here. It uses the collector PNP or drain Pch

Comment: Hello Antonio,i have a structure shown bellow.
How can i estimate the base and collector currents?
https://ibb.co/4NhS3VY

Comment: No load except diode leakage!  https://tinyurl.com/yz7cgs2p . try to learn useful circuits

Comment: Hello Tony,thank you for buiding the circuit.
but i really cannot understand the base current logic dinamics in a npn where base and collector has a resistor between them.

Do you have some manual i could read about such circuit.
Its not high end switch,its a switch with resistor between collector and base.I cant find analisis on such